# Program that shuffles cards, when I hit the shuffle button the cards dissappear on the GUI windows

Tags: javafx

All of my code so far, compiled fine, but the shuffle button makes all the cards disappear.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;

public class P6 extends Application
{
    public static final int ASIZE = 54;
    public static final int ROWS = 6;
    public static final int COLS = 9;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        int aCardDeck[] = new int[ASIZE];  // 54 cards in a deck
        for(int i = 0; i < ASIZE; i++)   // ASIZE is 54
            aCardDeck[i] = i + 1;          // Populate with elements 1-54

        GridPane gPane = new GridPane();   // Instantiate Grid for cards in rows/cols

        for(int i = 0, k = 0; i < ROWS && k < ASIZE; i++)  // 6 rows, 9 columns
            for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
                gPane.add(new ImageView("image/card/" + aCardDeck[k++] + ".png"), j, i);

        Button btShuffle = new Button("Shuffle");
        btShuffle.setOnAction
            (e ->                     // Lamda Event Handler
                {                      // Like anonymous inner class
                    int r, c, n;
                    shuffle(aCardDeck);         // Random shuffle
                    gPane.getChildren().clear();
                    for (r = n = 0; r < ROWS && n < ASIZE; r++)
                        for (c = 0; c < COLS; c++)
                            gPane.add(new ImageView("~/../public/image/card/" +
                                                    aCardDeck[n++] +
                                                    ".png"), c, r);
                }
            );

        HBox hBox = new HBox(5);              // Row of buttons
        hBox.getChildren().add(btShuffle);  // Add button to box

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(gPane);             // Layout rows of cards in center
        pane.setBottom(hBox);              // Layout buttons at bottom
        BorderPane.setAlignment(hBox, Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 650, 600); // Create scene, place in stage
        primaryStage.setTitle("P6");             // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);            // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show();                     // Display the stage
    }

    public void ascendSort (int [] a) {}
    public void descendSort (int [] a) {}
    public void ascendRankSort (int [] a) {}
    public void descendRankSort (int [] a) {}

    public void shuffle(int [] a) {
        int r, tmp;
        Random rand = new Random();
        long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        rand.setSeed(seed);
        for(int i = 0; i < ASIZE; i++) {
            r = rand.nextInt(ASIZE);

            tmp  = a[r];
            a[r] = a[i];
            a[i] = tmp;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg`enter code here`s)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The error messages:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1094)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:598)
    at javafx.scene.image.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:164)
    at P6.lambda$start$0(P6.java:39)
    at P6$$Lambda$1/16273898.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.access$200(GtkApplication.java:48)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$6$1.run(GtkApplication.java:149)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1086)
    ... 50 more
```

Comment: I don't know if this causing your bug (it might be) but you should not reload the images from disk on each shuffle. Maybe create a "Card" class and have the array hold cards rather than ints.  Put the image data into the Card class so you don't reload it every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I have an answer but I haven't tested it so I'm not sure.

But I believe your problem is inconsistent coding.

Here's the line you use at the beginning to fill gPane:

```
gPane.add(new ImageView("image/card/" + aCardDeck[k++] + ".png"),j,i);
```

And here's the line you use after you randomize:

```
gPane.add(new ImageView("~/../public/image/card/" + aCardDeck[n++]
        + ".png"),c,r);
```

The problem I think you are having is that `public/image/card` is the wrong path and you need to change it to make it the other path that you had. Also, I would make it a `refresh` method instead of copying that line of code everywhere. So you would call the `refresh` method everytime you changed the array instead of copy+pasting `gPane.add(...)` everywhere.